# Is it acceptable to submit papers anonymously to Computer Science conferences that don't ask for anonymity?

Tags: conference, peer-review, paper-submission, anonymity

Normally, a CS conference will give a clear indication in its Call For Paper (or in its submittion instruction) if the peer review of the conference is blind. However, if an author forget the anonymity requirement and submit a named paper, the result may be a merciless rejection even without any peer review. I have encountered such a thing, so I am just wondering is it acceptable to submit a anonymous paper to a conference even if the conference does not ask for it ? **whether an anonymous paper would cause some trouble to the reviewers or the Program Committee of a conference if the peer review is not blind?** Of course, the submittion system of a conference would record the information of all authors, including their names.

Comment: Why would he do that? To prove a point?

Comment: To avoid the mistake if the review is blind and I miss it

Comment: So you are suggesting to send everything at every conference without your name, just in case one of those hundreds CS conferences requires a blind review? That makes no sense. Would not it be easier to read more carefully the respective CFP?

Comment: Maybe I am not speaking clearly, but a submission system would record the information of the authors of the paper, including the names, and I just submit a anonymous paper file ("*.pdf" or "*.doc")

Comment: It will look like you took your previous rejection from a conference with blind submissions and resubmitted precisely the same document, without addressing any of the comments that you got or without even bothering to re-format the paper so that it follows the submission guidelines of the current conference. Most likely it will also be somewhat off-topic for this conference. Not the best possible first impression that you can give.

Comment: Let me rephrase: So you are suggesting to send anonymized PDFs at every conference, just in case one of those hundreds CS conferences requires a blind review? That makes no sense. Would not it be easier to read more carefully the respective CFP?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, JukkaSuomela and Alexandros. Over half of the top CS conferences require the blind review, and I certainly will re-format the same paper for different conferences, since they focus on different fields and apply different templates. I just want to develop a good 'habit' to avoid the same mistake when submitting a paper.

Comment: The habit you should cultivate is following the directions in the call for papers.

Comment: To restate, your concern is that you might accidentally submit an unblinded paper to a conference that wants blinded submissions, and have it rejected for failing to follow the guidelines.  You therefore propose to send blinded submissions to all conferences.  If you send a blinded submission to a conference that wants unblinded submissions, isn't it just as likely that they would similarly reject it for failing to follow the guidelines?

Comment: @NateEldredge Almost the same meaning. But I guess a blinded submission is  unlikely to be rejected even if the conference wants unblinded submissions. I am wondering whether a blinded submission would cause some unnecessary trouble for the reviewers or the Program Committee of this conference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a good idea. You just have to read every Call for Papers carefully and submit according to the instructions. That being said, I'm surprised that your program chair didn't ask you to resubmit with proper blinding instead of outright rejecting your paper. Submission errors happen, and authors are frequently given the opportunity to resubmit as long as the content isn't changed. The latter fact might be a little hard if the self-references weren't originally blinded, but I would think that most program chairs would have worked with you on this.

Comment: Thanks for your empathy. I am also surprised and regretful about the rejection, since my careless wastes all authors' plenty of time and effort. I think I should form a good habit to re-read the submission guideline carefully before the final submission, rather than simply submitting the anonymous paper.

Comment: At least if the CfP was very clear about the blindness requirement (thus making any unintentional mistake by the authors reasonably unlikely), I can imagine the non-blind submission was not so much seen as a "submission error [that] happen[s]", but as a possible deliberate attempt to get an unfair advantage over other submissions by means of personal or affiliation reputation and thus the program chair saw no point in rewarding that behaviour with a slight deadline extension to fix the issue.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I suppose that a program chair could choose to be that uncharitable, but why? If someone was a known repeat offender in this area, I could see using an outright rejection, but for a first offense, give me a break.

Comment: @BillBarth: Well, why give (assumed) offenders an extra bonus as a reward for their attempted fraud, compared to the other submitters who played fair? As I said, this is only valid if the blindness requirement was made really clear beforehand, in an *impossible to miss* way, in which case a deliberate act (or at least an unexcusable degree of sloppiness) might be assumed.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper revealing your true identity is not fraud.  Possibly unfair, but not fraud.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: If the rules for submitting explicitly specify that authors are required to blind their submission so the reviewers do not have a chance to learn about their true identity, then revealing one's true identity is a direct violation of the submission rules. Granted, *fraud* may not be the correct term for the kind of violation committed.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, what's the supposed bonus here? A slight amount of extra time because the blinding process was ignored? As long as the PC requires that no additional content be modified except that required to do the blinding, I think that's sufficient to make the process fair. A stern warning to follow the rules next time should also be sufficient to keep people from abusing the process.

Comment: @BillBarth: "As long as the PC requires that no additional content be modified" - true, that prevents the possible abuse, and just means the PC has to to some diffing, which they may or may not be willing to do.

Comment: I'm not surprised. Conferences I submit to do warn in their instructions to authors that submissions that haven't been anonymized will be rejected without review, and a conference I review for has, as the first question in the review form, "Is the submission anonymous?" (with instructions to stop the review there if the answer is 'no')

Comment: @ff524, interesting. Still seems overly punitive. I've definitely reviewed papers which had the names taken off the front but did a poor job of blinding the self-cites. How would this conference treat such a work? If the review successfully breaks the blind is it anonymous?